# Is "country" replaceable with "nation"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, word-in-context

In this sentence,

> The two pie charts illustrates distribution of water usage in a country in the years 1998 and 2008.

Can I replace the word **country** with the word **nation**?

Comment: Not in the case of the United Kingdom, which is four countries that make up one nation.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sorry I did not understand. If the country refers to the UK, then it is not replaceable. Right?

Comment: The UK is a nation, not a country. It consists of four countries: England, Wales, Scotland, and Northern Ireland.

Comment: "Country" is often interchangeable with "Nation"; however there are nations, like the United Kingdom, which are composed of multiple [constituent countries](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_country). In many cases, however, a nation can be referred to as a "country".

Comment: So you can't _always_ replace 'nation' with 'country' or vice versa; they are not always exact synonyms.

Comment: I have a question to this community.
Could this question be answered by using dictionaries? 
Because I haven't found any which can precisely tell me that these two words is not interchangeable.  
@Dialfrost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### You can not use the terms interchangeably.

The difference between countries and nations could fill entire lectures on history or political science. **The terms are also politically charged and subject of (sometimes violent) disagreements.** I'll try to give a brief explanation, just know that there may be disagreement on these terms and the examples I use.

##### Country:

Country is primarily a **geographical** term. A country has a territory over which it exerts control and can appear on a map. Countries are not necessarily independent (like the [constituent countries of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countries_of_the_United_Kingdom) or the countries in the [Kingdom of the Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_the_Netherlands)), but tend to have some power over their own affairs.

##### Nation:

A nation is primarily a **sociological** term. It describes a group of people with a common history, language, culture, or territory. Nations need not have a country and a country can be home to multiple nations. Examples for nations without countries include the [Kurds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdish_nationalism) and the [Navajo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navajo).

You also have issues of tourism and immigration. If a US national visits Europe, she may be in the country of France, but not a part of the French nation. Similarly, Qatar is a country with a lot of foreign workers. They are inhabitants of Qatar and count towards the population of the country. However, they are not members of the Qatari nation.

##### Your example

**Since the sentence talks about geographical data, you should not replace country with nation.**
The data likely includes the water used by tourists, immigrants and foreign corporations, all of which are not part of the nation.